# numpy.arange floating point errors

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, floating-point

Why does `np.arange(5, 60, 0.1)[150]` yield `19.999999999999947`. But `np.arange(5, 60, 0.5)[30]` yield `20.0`?

Why does this happen?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate In your case, 0.5 has an exact binary representation as a floating point number but 0.1 does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because floats (most of the time) cannot represent the exact value you put in. Try `print("%.25f" % np.float64(0.1))` which returns `0.1000000000000000055511151` that's not exactly `0.1`.

Numpy already provides a good workaround for almost-equal (floating point) comparisons: `np.testing.assert_almost_equal` so you can test by using `np.testing.assert_almost_equal(20,np.arange(5, 60, 0.1)[150])`.

The reason why your second example provides the real valus is because `0.5` can be represented as exact float `2**(-1) = 0.5` and therefore multiplications with this value do not suffer from that floating point problem.